# Does a newly-whistling skylight mean it is leaking air?

Tags: roof, skylight

We recently had the original roof of our 20-year-old townhouse removed and replaced. Since the completion of the work, windy days have seemed to cause different-from-before whistling around the skylight. I have not noticed any water leakage during the couple of rains we've had, one quite hard.

Does the new sound mean that the skylight is now leaking air? (Is that even possible?) Or is there a simple and perhaps common explanation like 'new flashing causes different air flow'? If the skylight has been compromised by the roofing job, which would be my guess if it's leaking air, I'd want to have it fixed since the roofers' work is warranted forever; but I don't want to start a fuss if this is normal.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: So the skylight has always been there and there's just new roofing?

Comment: Could it be a vibration from the flashing transmitting a noise? If there are no leaks it sounds like (pun intended) the roofers didn’t there job. Do you see any new holes?

Comment: @represton: Yes, the skylight has always been there, the only thing new is the roof and I guess whatever flashing etc goes into roofing next to the skylight.

Comment: @Ed Beal: I don't see any leaks/holes - but a big part of the issue is that the shaft up to the skylight, inside, is taller than any ladder we have, so I can't get up there to take a close look. Getting onto the roof is not an option for the same reason; it's a 3 story townhouse and I just don't have the ability to get up there.